# Percent sign crashes Twitter app

Tags: android, twitter

I am creating an Android app that allows users to create Tweets and then opens them in Twitter so that they can tweet them.  I am using the following code to get the text that they have entered and send it to Twitter:

```
String tweetUrl = "https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=" + URLEncoder.encode(mTweetTextBox.getText().toString());
Uri uri = Uri.parse(tweetUrl);
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri));
```

This all seems to work well in terms of encoding special characters, except when the user enters a percent sign.  This causes the Twitter app to crash if they select to use Twitter, but it works fine if they select to open the tweet in Chrome.  Any ideas what the problem might be or how I can resolve this?

This is the console output:

```
03-29 12:50:12.705: E/AndroidRuntime(24458):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2209)
03-29 12:50:12.705: E/AndroidRuntime(24458):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)
03-29 12:50:12.705: E/AndroidRuntime(24458):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
03-29 12:50:12.705: E/AndroidRuntime(24458):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
03-29 12:50:12.705: E/AndroidRuntime(24458):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-29 12:50:12.705: E/AndroidRuntime(24458):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-29 12:50:12.705: E/AndroidRuntime(24458):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5102)
03-29 12:50:12.705: E/AndroidRuntime(24458):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-29 12:50:12.705: E/AndroidRuntime(24458):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-29 12:50:12.705: E/AndroidRuntime(24458):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
03-29 12:50:12.705: E/AndroidRuntime(24458):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
03-29 12:50:12.705: E/AndroidRuntime(24458):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-29 12:50:12.705: E/AndroidRuntime(24458): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid % sequence at 5: test % tweet
03-29 12:50:12.705: E/AndroidRuntime(24458):    at libcore.net.UriCodec.decode(UriCodec.java:169)
03-29 12:50:12.705: E/AndroidRuntime(24458):    at java.net.URLDecoder.decode(URLDecoder.java:60)
03-29 12:50:12.705: E/AndroidRuntime(24458):    at com.twitter.library.util.Util.b(Twttr:369)
03-29 12:50:12.705: E/AndroidRuntime(24458):    at com.twitter.android.UrlInterpreterActivity.c(Twttr:631)
03-29 12:50:12.705: E/AndroidRuntime(24458):    at com.twitter.android.UrlInterpreterActivity.b(Twttr:237)
03-29 12:50:12.705: E/AndroidRuntime(24458):    at com.twitter.android.client.BaseFragmentActivity.onCreate(Twttr:313)
03-29 12:50:12.705: E/AndroidRuntime(24458):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5248)
03-29 12:50:12.705: E/AndroidRuntime(24458):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1110)
03-29 12:50:12.705: E/AndroidRuntime(24458):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2173)
03-29 12:50:12.705: E/AndroidRuntime(24458):    ... 11 more
```

Clearly its causing an `IllegalArgumentException` but I don't know how to get around this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The percent sign is used to encode special characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Url_encode). If you'd like to tweet "test % tweet", you would use the [special percent encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Url_encode#Percent-encoding_the_percent_character) instead:

```
    try {
        final String tweetUrl = "https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text="
                + URLEncoder.encode("test %25 tweet", "UTF-8");
        final Uri uri = Uri.parse(tweetUrl);
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri));
    } catch (final UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: This works, thanks!  Just wondering why `URLEncoder.encode` doesn't automatically encode the percent sign?

Comment: Well, it actually does. If you called `System.out.println(URLEncoder.encode("test % tweet", "UTF-8"))` you would see that it's encoded correctly, but I can't say why it didn't work in your case. The error seems to happen on Twitter's end, so I'd guess they're doing something.

Comment: @SamG-H I don't know why I didn't mention that in my post, I suppose I was more focused on solving it. You were right in using `URLEncoder.encode`.